How can I get distinct array fields efficiently?
My collection with fields:
[
  {
    "_id": xxx,
    "field": {
      "subfield": [
        {
          "k1": "a",
          "k2": "b",
          ...
        },
        {
          "k1": "a",
          "k2": "b",
          ...
        },
        {
          "k1": "c":
          "k2": "d",
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    "kn": "z",
    ...
  }
]

If subfield.0.k1 is a then subfield.0.k2 will always be b, etc.
I am trying to get the distinct values of k1 along with their value counts, and then the unique (singular) value of k2 that is associated with k1. But due to the amount of documents and variable-length arrays, trying to $unwind the matched documents in an aggregation pipeline kills the process or maxes out object size.
I managed to work within limits to retrieve value counts in PyMongo:
from collections import Counter
from pymongo import MongoClient


db = MongoClient(...).get_database(...).get_collection(...)

query = [
   {"$match": {"kn": "z"}},
   {"$group": {"_id": "$field.subfield.k1", "count": {"$sum": 1}}}
]
results = list(db.aggregate(query))  # this returns a list of dicts where grouped unique _id is an array
results = [d["_id"] * d["count"] for d in results]  # expanding these list _ids enables us to get value counts
results = [element for sublist in results for element in sublist]
results = Counter(results)

I'm looking for a way to find the unique value of k2 associated with each value of k1. I could find_one() each returned counter value, but this is too time-consuming.

$unwind and perform grouped count as you have attempted would be the canonical way to achieve what you want. If your use case is a frequent one, you should consider storing the array entries as individual documents and index them to make performant queries.

Did you try simple $setUnion: "$subfield"?

@WernfriedDomscheit this seems promising but $setUnion seems to take an array, so I'm not sure how the expression above would be applicable...
